# Making the edge of a road blend in with the terrain

Tags: bezier-curves, path

How would you go about making the edge of a road blend in with the surrounding terrain, while maintaining modeling controls for the road such as following a curved path. Can it still be a separate object, or does it have to be embedded into the terrain?

[image]

[image]

The most obvious example is a snowy/dirt road.

[image]

Comment: Hi :). An obvious way is to use particles like in real world. Grass, gravel, pebbles, or large  stones. Without those, even real asphalt [looks like this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/2019-images-allaboutdriveways.com/asphalt-faqs/asphalt-driveway-edges.png)

Comment: Also, use one material for both the road and the grass, and separate them with a b&w mask that you plug into a Mix Shader?

Comment: an obvious way is to use geometry nodes, because you have far more possibilities than with particles ;)

Comment: @Chris Well that's obviously obvious (obviousness all around) :))

Comment: I would be interested in this too and the closest thing I could find was this tutorial on proximity based blending:
https://youtu.be/4BTM4YPAeh0 All suggestions about particles and geometry nodes basically just try to hide the gap and need a lot of instances. Usually the terrain would still have a simple texture for dirt/earth/sand and it should randomly bleed into the road asphalt texture as perfectly illustrated by Mike's photo examples. If there is a good tutorial somewhere that still keeps the street as separate object, please share it here. Thanks